# Postgresql: How to search jsonb for LIKE value

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I want to see if a string is in the values anywhere within a jsonb. Not interested in the keys, just values.

Something like

```
select
    the_reults
  from
    my_database
  where
    jsonb->>'*' LIKE '%123456%'
  group by
    whatever
  order by
    whatever
```

Wildcard for the key doesn't work. It could be that 123456 is a number though.

Any ideas there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
select
    the_results
  from
    my_database
 where 
    jsonb_path_exists (jsonb, '$.** ? (exists(@ like_regex "123456"))')
  group by
    whatever
  order by
    whatever
```

Comment: It's not working. I am wondering if i have a true jsonb. Here's what it looks like:

{thing=value, thing1=value2, thing3=aBUNCHofTEXT}

Comment: I confirm that `{thing=value, thing1=value2, thing3=aBUNCHofTEXT}` is not a json data, maybe `{"thing": "value", "thing1": "value2", "thing3": "aBUNCHofTEXT"}`

Comment: Right, but I don't have control of the "object", whatever it is. Any other method to search it?

Comment: You can directly use a regular expression : `WHERE jsonb :: text ~ '123456'